# How to avoid drawImage() starburst artifacts?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

## 1. Original Question:

I'm doing a canvas animation "zoom" effect that is producing some annoying visual artifacts. This simplified example shows the output after 255 frames. In each frame, two things happen: (1) `drawArc()` makes a colored (gray) disk at the center of the canvas; (2) `imageDraw()` redraws the canvas at a slightly enlarged scale. I'd expect to see a smooth radial gradient expanding outward from the center. Instead this is what I see:

[image: zzz]

What bugs me are (a) the bright "starbursts" along the vertical and horizontal axes (and to a lesser extent, on the diagonals) and (b) the fuzzy diamond-shaped pattern.

I figure this is some sort of artifact of `drawImage()`'s scaling algorithm. I've tried tweaking all the parameters (`delta`, `strokeWidth`, arc radius), but there's always some version of this starburst effect. Any suggestions on how to avoid -- or at least reduce -- this effect?

Here's my code:

```
var cv = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
var cvHeight = cv.height;
var cvWidth = cv.width;
for (var j=0;j<255;j++) {
    var delta = 4;

    // redraw the canvas, enlarged by delta pixels
    ctx.drawImage(cv, 0, 0, cvWidth, cvHeight, 
        -delta/2, -delta/2, cvWidth+delta, cvHeight+delta);

    // draw a new circle at the center, in a different color
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb("+ j + "," + j + "," + j +")";
    ctx.strokeWidth = 10;
    ctx.arc(cvWidth/2, cvHeight/2, 10, 0, Math.PI*2.0);    
    ctx.stroke();   
}
```

Here's [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7kdkpcd).

## 2. Further elaboration

As @Igor Raush aptly observed, the example image I gave can be rendered better (starburst-free) with `createRadialGradient()`. But my example code was oversimplified and misleading: My goal is not to generate radial color gradients, but to create a zoom animation effect by enlarging the canvas with successive calls to `imageDraw()`. In the above example a static white disc was placed at the center of the canvas. In my actual application, a new image is placed at the center of the canvas in each frame. The problem is that, no matter what kind of image is originally placed at the center of the canvas, those annoying starburst patterns will appear to some degree.

Here's a better example that uses random data and real animation. (I'm using random data here for simplicity. The actual data in my application is not random, but the effect is identical.) In each frame, a ring (`ctx.arc()`) of randomly colored points is drawn at the center of the canvas; `imageDraw()` then expands the canvas slightly.

Here's the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvtk65uc/), and here's the code:

```
var cv = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
var cvHeight = cv.height;
var cvWidth = cv.width;
var delta = 10; // higher = faster "expansion" of the canvas
var data = new Array(100);

setInterval( function() { 
    FetchNewData(data); // fill the array with new data
    DrawTheRing(cv,data); // draw the data around a ring, as shades of gray, centered on the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(cv, 0, 0, cvWidth, cvHeight, -delta/2, -delta/2, cvWidth+delta, cvHeight+delta); // expand the canvas
} , 10);


// Load up the array with random data
function FetchNewData(data) {
    var nSamples = data.length;
    for (var k=0; k< nSamples; k++) {
        data[k] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
    }
}

// draw a ring, centered on the canvas, containing the grayscale data
function DrawTheRing(cv,data) {
    var radius = 10;
    var thickness = 10;
    var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
    var angle = 0;
    var dAngle = Math.PI*2.0/data.length;
    for ( var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
        var value = data[k];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb("+ value + "," + value + "," + value +")";    // a shade of gray
        ctx.arc(cvWidth/2, cvHeight/2, radius, angle, angle+dAngle);    
        ctx.stroke();    
        angle += dAngle;
    }
}
```

Here's a snapshot of it in action:
[image: zoooming with random data]

Any ideas on how to avoid those spurious sharp lines on the vertical and horizontal axes and on the diagonals? Is there a better way to accomplish this kind of zooming effect?

Answer (score 2):

The imperfections are indeed due to scaling. As soon as you draw a path onto the canvas, the path information is lost, so you are resizing a rasterized version of the image. This is why your circles end up looking like polygons.

You can instead use [ctx.createRadialGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient), animate the color stops, and repaint the canvas every frame.

```
var s = 0.99;
var x = cvWidth / 2,
    y = cvHeight / 2,
    r = cvWidth / 2;

// generate gradient
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, r, x, y, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'black');
gradient.addColorStop(s, 'black');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5jbf2ok7/) is an example Fiddle. You can play around with the inner circle radius and the timing function controlling your color stops to achieve the result you want.

Comment: +1 thanks. Unfortunately, my question wasn't clear, and I oversimplified my example. I'm actually not trying to draw radial color gradients, but to find a general way to do this sort of "expanding canvas" animation, without those spurious starbursts. I need to re-think & re-write my original question, and come up with a better example. Stay tuned...

Comment: @jt Got it. A more real-world example would help. The high-level idea will probably still hold: don't take high-quality graphics, scale them down, rasterize them, and scale them back up. Instead, redraw elements on every frame at the size that you need them.

Comment: I just edited my question with a slightly more "real-world" example. I welcome any comments/answers!